# Using useState in useEffect to pass context.provider values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I'm trying to set up a main context data object that can then be passed into my application, to server as a main pool/state.

The problem i'm having, is im trying to set up and define the state in the parent component using `useState` in `useEffect` before passing it into the `Context.Provider` as a `value`.

However, when trying to access the contexts value in child components, im getting an empty object.

I'm assuming it's because `useEffect` is potentially being called/finishing after the component has mounted/rendered. But if that is the case, how do I make sure that the `contextMain` data object is populated, before the component mounts, so that the data is all present and available down the render pipeline?

```
export default function App() {
    const [contextMain, setContextMain] = React.useState({});
    const [context1, setContext1] = React.useState([]);
    const [context2, setContext2] = React.useState([]);

    const c1 = ['a', 'b'];
    const c2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setContext1(c1);
        setContext2(c2);
        setContextMain(prevObject => ({
            ...prevObject,
            context1: c1,
            context2: c2,
        }));
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Context.Provider value={contextMain}>
                <RouterProvider router={router} />
            </Context.Provider>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

useEffect is called after render thats why your context is empty.

1. You can set an `initialized` prop and/or make all the fields nullable
2. You use getters and throw an error when a field is accessed before the context is initialized.
3. You only render children when your context is ready:

```
  return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <Context.Provider value={contextMain}>
              {contextMain.initialized && <RouterProvider router={router} />}
          </Context.Provider>
      </React.Fragment>
  );
```

In general most changes to state/context happen after the user has done an action ie. after the first rendering and therefore your context should be available.

Aside from that you shouldnt use one big context to store your state but separate state/context by functionality because if you have one big context all the consumers will update when any of the vars in the context change which is pretty bad.

Also I wouldnt merge other contexts inside your context.
If anyone else wants to consume a context they can just do it by themselves.

Comment: ah ok, so does that mean that functional components dont have an equivelant to `componentWillMout()`?. Also, i tried adding `contextMain.initialized` but it is never true. I'm sure I'm probably missing something there XD

Comment: Cant judge without code. componentWillMount is unsafe and shouldnt be used anyways. I would use `useMemo` instead of `useState` for you context so you only update it when a dependency changes and the initial value should be calculated before the component is rendered for the first time.